# Installer is asking about x86 and x64 - what are they? 

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm running Windows Vista 32-bit with 2 GB RAM. I want to install Windows 7.

The install is asking what architecture, X86 or X64. I was thinking it would be asking 32-bit?

What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

"x86" is the name for standard 32-bit processors. The full name for a 64-bit processor is "x86-64".

See Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86